# Link not working on image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been attempting to create an effect where a user clicks on an image, that image is replaced by another image which also acts as a link.

However my problem is that whenever I click the replaced image, the link doesn't work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ha6qp7w4/321/

```
$('.btnClick').on('click',function(){
    $(this).attr('src','https://placekitten.com/g/200/300')
    $(this).attr('href','google.com')
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/ha6qp7w4/309/ ?

Comment: yep! But do you know why the link doesn't work? Even if I replace href with "google.com".

Comment: your code seems very complicated... Why don't you simple use $('#yourImg').show() and $('#yourImg').hide() ?  Or, I think you can replace the src attribute...

Answer (score 2):

`img` tags don't have `href` properties. You need to wrap the image in an anchor and assign the url to that, or do a custom redirect.

Notice your image html on inspection of element:

```
<img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" id="1" class="btnClick" href="google.com"> <!-- not valid! -->
```

This isn't valid because imgs aren't anchors!

```
function first() {
    this.src = 'https://placekitten.com/g/200/300';
    $(this).unbind("click");
    $(this).on("click", second);
}

function second() {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
    $(this).unbind("click");
    $(this).on("click", first);
}

$('.btnClick').on('click', first);
```

(I tried to make a fiddle but it wouldn't save, but this should work)

You need to store your actions in functions so you can revert if need be. First action is the change the source, then change the event to redirect you like a link.

Comment: Thx Sterling bae <3, it's a shame the link didn't work but nice try :

Comment: It looks like jsfiddle is messing up, it didn't save my functions. Lemme try again

Answer (score -1):

here is an example.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ha6qp7w4/312/)

html part

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/o46X87d.png" data-new="http://i.imgur.com/9lf2Mjk.png" id="1" class="btnClick" />
```

add data-new attribute on image with new url of image 
and replace it with js

```
$('.btnClick').on('click',function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("data-new");

    $(this).attr("src", url);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use a totally different approach, but here's how to do that with the code you already have:

```
<div class="btnClick">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/o46X87d.png" id="1" />
<a href="javascript:check()" id="2" style="display:none;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9lf2Mjk.png" id="static" />
</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.btnClick').on('click',function(){
    if($('#1').is(':visible')) {
        $('#1').hide();
        $('#2').show();
    } else {
        $('#1').show();
        $('#2').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

I purposely didn't use `toggle()` to better show the technique, in case you'd want to turn the click event off when the clicking image appears etc.